# Guid型の静的フィールドの初期化のパラメータにconst値を使っても大丈夫か？

Tags: c#

`Guid`は`const`として扱うことができないため、下記のようにGUID値を文字列定数にして`public static`な`Guid`値にしています。

初期化の順番が`NullObjectGuidSingleton`、`GuidText`の順になるなど、
環境によって変わることがありえますか？

ありえるなら、`Guid`のコンストラクタに同じものを書くのは避けたいのですが、
どのようにコーディングするのがよいでしょうか？

```
public sealed class NullObject : IGameObject
{
    private const string GuidText = "1887ABDE-4B0B-4D87-860B-1E811CCE3A89";
    public static readonly Guid NullObjectGuidSingleton = new Guid(GuidText);
    // ...
```

Comment: 余談ですが、 [`Guid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/System.Guid(v=vs.110).aspx) は構造体なのでシングルトンと言うには違和感があります。

Comment: `Guid`は生成に文字列パースのコストがかかりますし、値も不変なので一回だけ生成して使いまわすという意味でシングルトンパターンに沿っていると思ってます。
unaristさんの基準はどこでしょう？
C#での実装がstructだとシングルトンではないというのであれば、`Guid?`型になればシングルトンと言っても構わないのでしょうか？
Javaでは`UUID`クラスですが、この場合はシングルトンと言ってよいででしょうか？

Comment: 一度生成した `Guid` を使いまわすことに異論はないです。気になったのは、実体を共有することのできない値型でも「シングルトン」と言うのだろうか？という点だけですが、仰る通り `Guid` の値は不変なので実際にそこが何か問題になることはないと思います。ちなみに [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) も構造体です。

Comment: なるほど、不変なので実体の共有という観点は頭になかったです。`readonly` じゃない構造体はシングルトンとは絶対に呼べませんものね。
あと、構造体`Nullable<T>`なのですね。VM内部でボクシングされているのかと思ってました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

定数式は必ず`static`フィールド初期化子より先に評価されるので質問文の書き方で問題ありません。
なお同一クラスの`static`フィールド初期化子は上から順に評価されますので注意が必要です。

Answer (score 2):

const はコンパイル時に初期化されます。
readonly は実行時になります。ですのでconstが先に初期化という認識で正しいです。

ちなみに、一般的にシングルトンはインスタンス(メモリ上に配置された状態)が実行時に１つだけになる実装パターンを指します。
Guid? は単に参照型であるGuidをnullの状態を持つことができるようにしただけです。
Guid?はいくつも宣言できその値が別の値を保持できますので、シングルトンとは呼びません。

シングルトンを詳しく知りたいのであれば、GoFのデザインパターンを調べてみると良いですよ。

```
// シングルトンの簡単な実装。C#でのシングルトンの実装は他にもパターンがあります。
public sealed class Singleton`
{
    // これがシングルトンのインスタンス
    public static Singleton Instance = new Singelton();

    // 外からインスタンス化できない用にprivateのコンストラクタを宣言
    private Singleton()
    {
    } 
}
```